# How to get rows with min values in one column, grouped by other column, while keeping other columns?

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), B=c("P","P","P","Q","Q","Q"), C=c("a","b","c","d","e","f"))
df
##      A B C
##    1 1 P a
##    2 2 P b
##    3 3 P c
##    4 4 Q d
##    5 5 Q e
##    6 6 Q f
```

I want to somehow get the rows with the minimum value in A for each distinct B, but also with the corresponding value in C. e.g.

```
##      A B C
##    1 1 P a
##    4 4 Q d
```

I tried the following, but neither does what I would want:

```
> aggregate(df[c('A')], by=df[c('B')], FUN=min)
  B A
1 P 1
2 Q 4
> aggregate(df[c('A')], by=df[c('B','C')], FUN=min)
  B C A
1 P a 1
2 P b 2
3 P c 3
4 Q d 4
5 Q e 5
6 Q f 6
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(B) %>%
    filter(A==min(A))
#  A B C
#1 1 P a
#2 4 Q d
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[A==min(A)], B]
```

Or using `base R`

```
 df[with(df, ave(A, B, FUN=min)==A),]
 #  A B C
 #1 1 P a
 #4 4 Q d
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using the `dplyr` solution. But: as it is, it outputs multiple rows for a group, if the minimum value occurs multiple times, since I did not want that, I used: `df %>% group_by(B) %>% filter(A==min(A)) %>% distinct(A)`

Comment: @DimitriSchachmann  If you have ties and need the first value, you could also use `which.min`  i.e. `df %>% group_by(B) %>% slice(which.min(B))`

Answer (score 1):

you can also use the split-apply technique:

```
# split `df` on the field 'b' 
tmp <- split(df,df$B)

# reduce to the row with the minimum value of A
tmp  <-  lapply(tmp,function(x)
                x[x$A == min(x$A),])

# bind the rows together
do.call(rbind,tmp)


#>   A B C
#> P 1 P a
#> Q 4 Q d
```