# Get the corresponding values of a remaining columns with respect to a group_by max value

Tags: r, dplyr

This the data, from a **group_by Id** data frame I need a **max** value from Mean column and its(max Mean) **corresponding** values from remaining columns.

*summarise_each_* --> gives me max value from all the columns, whereas I just need their corresponding values for max of Mean.

```
    Id RadarSeries      Mean TimeToEnd DistanceToRadar Composite HybridScan
1   1           1 11.125000        56              30     -14.0      -14.0
2   2           1  7.416667        58              77     -14.0      -14.0
3   3           1  5.250000        59              75     -14.0      -14.0
4   4           1 12.750000        53              21     -14.0      -14.0
5   5           1 15.000000        56              69      24.0       19.0
6   5           2 21.916667        59              83      18.5       19.5
7   5           3 17.833333        57              54      23.0       23.5
8   5           4 19.312500        59               3      23.0       27.0
9   5           5 19.937500        58              60      26.0       23.5
10  5           6  9.000000        55              58      28.0      -14.0
11  6           1  5.000000        56               1      -4.0      -14.0
12  7           1 10.464286        59              42     -14.0      -14.0
13  8           1 29.277778        57              10      39.5       47.0
14  8           2 17.500000        43               8     -14.0      -14.0
15  8           3 23.500000        57              20      23.5       17.5
16  9           1 11.250000        36              92     -14.0      -14.0
17 10           1 12.500000        15              90      13.0       13.5
18 10           2  7.666667        53              63     -14.0       -5.0
19 10           3 11.000000        14              12      11.5       11.5
```

Comment: Perhaps `df1 %>% group_by(Id) %>% filter(Mean==max(Mean))`  Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458833/how-to-get-rows-with-min-values-in-one-column-grouped-by-other-column-while-ke

Comment: Or try `df %>% group_by(Id) %>% slice(which.max(Mean))`

Comment: thanks! both of them are working. I was struggling a lot using summarise().

Comment: FYI, there's a subtle difference between the two approaches. The first will return all rows with the max value in "Mean" column while the second approach will only return the row with with the first max value in "Mean" column.