# How to find min value of grouped data on column A and min of the other column B when duplicate values exist on A

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am trying to analyse a dataframe using Pandas. My question is similar to the question:

[How to get rows with min values in one column, grouped by other column, while keeping other columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458833/how-to-get-rows-with-min-values-in-one-column-grouped-by-other-column-while-ke)

In addition to that question (which is very important in my case), I also need to find the min value of the other columns if there are multiple min values for grouped column. If not, I need to see the corresponding values.

Here is a basic example;

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,1,1,2,2],
                   'A' : [8,6,6,8,9],
                   'B' : [1,2,4,5,4]})
```

When this dataframe is grouped by 'id' and aggregated (first on 'A', then on 'B') as I want, here is the output I want to see:

```
id  A   B   
1   6   2
2   8   5
```

Note that, there are multiple rows having min value for the column 'A' when id is 1. The corresponding 'B' column values are 2 and 4. Thus, the min of them is returned as the result for the 'B' column.

I do not know R, so, I did not understand the answer from the link above. Anyway, this is a different version of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, using `idxmin` after sorting by `B`

---

```
df.loc[df.sort_values('B').groupby('id')['A'].idxmin()]
```

```
   id  A  B
1   1  6  2
3   2  8  5
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is taking advantage of `groupby` sorts `group_keys` by default. So, groupby `'id,  A'` will push groups of min `A` per `ID` to the top. After that, call `min` on `B`, `reset_index` and `drop_duplicate`

```
df.groupby(['id', 'A'])['B'].min().reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset='id')


Out[298]:
   id  A  B
0   1  6  2
2   2  8  5
```